# C# Data Grid View DataError Event not Triggering

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm relatively new to programming and I've been trying to make a C# Windows Forms Application that connects to a MySQL database.

I have everything working except when a part of the table is ready with invalid data, then I get a DataError message. I have tried adding  an event to stop the default error dialog but no matter what I still get it. I've been searching for solutions for about 3 hours but no luck yet.

I added this code to my program for the event:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

The default error still comes up. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to solve this problem?